# Check if anonymous in HTTPModule

Tags: httpmodule

I'm in the process of writing an HTTPModule in C#.NET that manages unhandled errors by our applications on a particular server. Some users are in our domain, some are anonymous. How can I determine in my HTTPModule whether the user is anonymous or from our domain?

Answer (score 0):

First in IIS you have to activate [Windows authentication](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication#004).
Then you have access to the current user with `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity`